# Git Tower push to Github and Beanstalk

Tags: git-tower

Is it possible to publish to multiple remote repositories? I have accounts at Github and Beanstalk, would like to publish a local project to both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's possible. You simply need to add another remote repository to your local repo:
http://www.git-tower.com/files/applicationHelp/pgs/Refs_Remotes_Add.html

Then, you'll be able to push to any of these (using the toolbar button or simply via drag and drop). If you have any more questions get in touch via support[at]git-tower[dot]com